# How to notice tabbing into a text input field

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I need to call a function whenever a user "selects" an input text field, meaning they can type in it. Currenty I am using a click as the trigger, but it occurred to me a user can also tab into the field. What is a more general trigger for a user selecting an input field.

E.g using vue.js

```
<input type='text' @click='certainFunction'>
// @click doesnt respond to tabbing into the input field.
// What should replace @click?
```

Comment: What do you want to do? You say, 'selects' that means you have a select tag (for dropdown) and not an input

Answer (score 2):

A more general trigger is when a user focuses on the input.

It is done by the `focus` event.

So something like

`@focus='certainFunction'`

It doesn't matter if he got there by clicking or tabbing, he is still focused on the input.